# Spring TaskScheduling with HashMap

Tags: java, thread-safety, spring

I am currently developing a Task Scheduler to run different methods at a certain time. In general it is a Spring-boot application an task execution/scheduling is just a very tiny piece of the whole project. My idea is to define several Runnables  that execute depending on a CronTrigger. In the Runnable I create an object `Job` that holds information about the current task, like `startTime`, `status` and others.

```
public class Job {
    private Long          id;
    private Class         clazz;
    private Date          startTime;
    private boolean       status;
    private String        parameter;
    private CronTrigger   cronTrigger;
    private String        exception;

    Job(long id, Class<?> clazz, boolean status, Date startTime, String parameter, CronTrigger cronTrigger, String exception) {
        this.id = id;
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.status = status;
        this.parameter = parameter;
        this.cronTrigger = cronTrigger;
        this.exception = exception;
    }

    //Getter, Setter, toString()
}
```

To represent which thread is currently running/waiting I add it to `ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Job>` there are two, one for sleeping Thread and one for running Threads.
There are also two methods `addTask(Long task, Job job)` and `removeTask(Long task, Job job)` that put/remove Jobs to/from the two ConcurrentHashMaps and set `status` of an `Job`.

```
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

private HashMap<Long, CronTrigger> cronTriggers = new HashMap<>();

private ScheduledFuture<?> task0;
private ScheduledFuture<?> task1;
private ScheduledFuture<?> task2;
private ScheduledFuture<?> task3;
private ScheduledFuture<?> task4;
private ScheduledFuture<?> task5;
private ScheduledFuture<?> task6;
private ScheduledFuture<?> task7;
private ScheduledFuture<?> task8;
private ScheduledFuture<?> task9;

private final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Job> scheduledTasksRunning = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Job> scheduledTasksSleeping = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private Job selectedScheduledJob;

private int POOL_SIZE = 10;

@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {

    this.scheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
    this.scheduler.initialize();

    for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++){
        cronTriggers.put(((long) i), new CronTrigger("1 1 1 1 * *"));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++){
        Job job = new Job((long) i, getClass(), false, new Date(),null, cronTriggers.get((long) i), null);
        scheduledTasksSleeping.put(((long) i), job);
    }

    task0 = scheduler.schedule(new Task0(), cronTriggers.get(0L));
    task1 = scheduler.schedule(new Task1(), cronTriggers.get(1L));
    task2 = scheduler.schedule(new Task2(), cronTriggers.get(2L));
    task3 = scheduler.schedule(new Task3(), cronTriggers.get(3L));
    task4 = scheduler.schedule(new Task4(), cronTriggers.get(4L));
    task5 = scheduler.schedule(new Task5(), cronTriggers.get(5L));
    task6 = scheduler.schedule(new Task6(), cronTriggers.get(6L));
    task7 = scheduler.schedule(new Task7(), cronTriggers.get(7L));
    task8 = scheduler.schedule(new Task8(), cronTriggers.get(8L));
    task9 = scheduler.schedule(new Task9(), cronTriggers.get(9L));
    return scheduler;
}

public class Task0 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Long id = 0L;
        Job job = new Job(id, getClass(), true, new Date(), null, cronTriggers.get(id), null);
        addTask(id, job);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            job.setException(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        removeTask(id, job);
    }
}

public class Task1 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Long id = 1L;
        Job job = new Job(id, getClass(), true, new Date(), null, cronTriggers.get(id), null);
        addTask(id, job);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            job.setException(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        removeTask(id, job);
    }
}

// 8 other Runnables


/**
 * manually stop a running Job via GUI
 *
 */
public void taskCancel(){
    Long id = selectedScheduledJob.getId();
    switch (toIntExact(id)){
    case 0:
        task0.cancel(true);
        break;
    case 1:
        task1.cancel(true);
        break;
    // 8 other cases for each Thread
    }
}

/**
 * manually start a selected Job via GUI and force it to trigger at next
 * scheduled time
 */
public void taskStart(){
    Long id = selectedScheduledJob.getId();
    switch (toIntExact(id)){

    case 0:
        scheduler.schedule(new Task0(), new Date());
        scheduler.schedule(new Task0(), cronTriggers.get(id));
        break;
    case 1:
        scheduler.schedule(new Task1(), new Date());
        scheduler.schedule(new Task1(), cronTriggers.get(id));
        break;
    // 8 other cases for each Thread
    }
}

private synchronized void addTask(Long task, Job job) {
    scheduledTasksSleeping.remove(task);
    scheduledTasksRunning.put(task, job);
}

private synchronized void removeTask(Long task, Job job) {
    job.setStatus(false);
    scheduledTasksRunning.remove(task);
    scheduledTasksSleeping.put(task, job);
}

// Getter and Setter for GUI
```

I know however that the definition of `ScheduledFuture<?> taskX;` is not that good and I tend to use a `ArrayList` in future.

Some things I am interested in:

- Is there anything I did that is blatantly the wrong way of doing it?
- Do you see any way to improve the performance or speed?
- Is it thread-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already mentioned your definition of the `ScheduledFuture<?>` instances could be improved with an `ArrayList`.

```
for (long i=0; i<9; i++) {
    tasks[i] =  scheduler.schedule(new Task(i), cronTriggers.get(i));
}
```

Instead of 10 class definitions for the tasks you could set the `id` for your task in the constructor as you define the array of tasks. This will make your code more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and easier to maintain.

```
public class Task implements Runnable {    
    private long id;
    public Task(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void run() {
        Job job = new Job(
            id, getClass(), true, new Date(), null, cronTriggers.get(this.id), null);
        addTask(this.id, job);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            job.setException(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        removeTask(this.id, job);
    }
}
```